# Optimizing/improving speed of simple bit of Python code

Tags: python, performance, optimization, time

I have a list of *customers*, and I wish to return a sorted list of the customers that occur more
than 5% of the time in the original list. The following works, but I need to optimize it. Unfortunately, I am unable to discover how to (drastically) improve the time efficiency. Any suggestions?

```
def mostActive(customers):
    unique_customers = set(customers)
    count = len(customers)
    result = []
    for customer in unique_customers:
        if customers.count(customer) / count >= .05:
            result.append(customer)
    return sorted(result)
```

Comment: Try list comprehension. It will make your code more simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from collections import Counter

def mostActive(customers):
    return sorted(customer
                  for customer, count in Counter(customers).items()
                  if count / len(customers) >= .05)
```

Using `collections.Counter` to count the occurrences of each element in the list dramatically increases the performance. Indeed you count the occurrences just once, in linear time. So here the complexity is O(n) + O(nlog(n)) (sorting the results is now the bottleneck).

Answer (score 2):

When talking performance, testing is key. Here's the runtime (on my machine, ofc) of some of the codes presented in the other answers, the original code and a numpy-based answer (all codes run on the same data):

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import time

random_data = np.random.randint(0, 100, [100, 100000])

#### Original code
def mostActive(customers):
    unique_customers = set(customers)
    count = len(customers)
    result = []
    for customer in unique_customers:
        if customers.tolist().count(customer) / count >= .05: # had to add .tolist() to make it compatible with the data
            result.append(customer)
    return sorted(result)

start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
  _ = mostActive(random_data[i])
end = time.time()
print(f'Avg time: {(end-start)*10} ms') # would be /100*1000 -> simplified to *10
# Avg time: 1394.4847583770752 ms

#### Sorted + Counter

def mostActive(customers):
    return sorted(customer
                  for customer, count in Counter(customers).items()
                  if count / len(customers) >= .05)

start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
  _ = mostActive(random_data[i])
end = time.time()
print(f'Avg time: {(end-start)*10} ms')
# Avg time: 16.061179637908936 ms

#### Numpy

start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
  unique_elements, counts = np.unique(random_data[i], return_counts=True)
  active = sorted(unique_elements[counts > 0.05*len(random_data[i])])
end = time.time()
print(f'Avg time: {(end-start)*10} ms')
# Avg time: 3.5660386085510254 ms
```

Unsurprisingly, the numpy-only solution is ligtning-fast (thanks to the underlying high-performance C implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
list(set([name for name in customers if customers.count(name)/len(customers)>=0.05]))
```

Comment: This does not improve the performance as you are still counting every time. The complexity is at least quadratic.